# Atlas Messages RecyclerView image bind with Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I'm using AtlasMessagesRecyclerView  as Ui helper with layer sdk so 
when it bind an image which have been sent using gallery or camera picasso give that exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unrecognized type of request: Request{layer:///messages/61ca843f-407c-479e-a7ee-15f1be648263/parts/1 RoundedTransform.45.0 resize(936,702)}    '
```

and this AtlasMessagesRecyclerView setup :

```
Picasso picasso =  new Picasso
            .Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .executor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
            .indicatorsEnabled(true)
            .loggingEnabled(true)
           .memoryCache(new LruCache(this))
           .listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
               @Override
               public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
                   Log.e("Picasso" , "Uri"+uri.toString());
                   Log.e("Picasso" , "exception"+exception.toString());
                   exception.printStackTrace();
               }
           })
            .build();

messagesList = ((AtlasMessagesRecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messageslist))
            .init(layerClient,picasso )
            .setConversation(conversation)
            .addCellFactories(
                    new ThreePartImageCellFactory(layerClient,picasso),
                    new TextCellFactory(),
                    new LocationCellFactory(picasso)
                    );
```